# How to remove phpmyadmin on debian without removing databases, users, privileges,

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, debian, apt, dpkg

I have a vps with mysql and phpmyadmin on debian 7.
I have create a super user with remote access to mysql.
I have access to phpmyadmin with my-ip/phpmyadmin.
I want to completly remove phpmyadmin but I want to keep my remote access, my databases, privileges, etc...

I read differents answers, witch one is good ?

Solution 1 :

```
sudo dpkg -P phpmyadmin  
sudo rm -f /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Solution 2 :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove phpmyadmin
```

Solution 3 :

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your solution 1 and 3 are essentially the same (using different tools to accomplish the same task; except you shouldn't need to rm the .conf file or restart Apache on your own). Solution 2 does not do what you think it does, try `man apt-get` and search for autoremove.

This should be safe to do without affecting the MySQL database, with the caveat that if your MySQL depends on phpMyAdmin and nothing else does, it might be removed. I often work in Aptitude because I like the interface, but apt-get will show you what's about to be done as well. Try first with `apt-get --dry-run purge phpmyadmin` and closely examine the list of packages to be removed.

When phpMyAdmin is installed, a 'controluser' and special administrative database are created. Those will be removed, but since they're only used by phpMyAdmin, there's no problem with them being deleted when purging the package.

Still, it's always good to have up to date backups before making any changes.